# Cannot import SQLite with Python 2.6

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm running Python 2.6 on Unix and when I run the interactive prompt ([SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) is supposed to be preinstalled) I get:

```
[root@idev htdocs]# python
Python 2.6 (r26:66714, Oct 23 2008, 16:25:34)
[GCC 3.2.2 20030222 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.2-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sqlite
>>>
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error:

```
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

means that [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) 3 does not find the associated shared library. On Mac OS X it's _sqlite3.so and it should be the same on other Unix systems.

To resolve the error you have to locate the _sqlite3.so library on your computer and then check your PYTHONPATH for this directory location.

To print the Python search path enter the following in the Python shell:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If the directory containing your library is missing you can try adding it interactively with

```
sys.path.append('/your/dir/here')
```

and try

```
import sqlite3
```

again. If this works you have to add this directory permanently to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

PS: If the library is missing you should (re-)install the module.

Answer (score 10):

```
import sqlite3
```

[sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) - DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases.

You are missing the `.so` (shared object) - probably an installation step. In my Linux python installation, `_sqlite3` is at:

```
${somewhere}/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
```

Answer (score 10):

Python 2.6 detects where the sqlite3 development headers are installed, and will silently skip building _sqlite3 if it is not available. If you are building from source, install sqlite3 including development headers. In my case, `sudo yum install sqlite-devel` sorted this out on a CentOS 4.7. Then, rebuild Python from source code.

Comment: please clarify what 'rebuild Python from source code' means. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

On my system `_sqlite3.so` located at:

```
'/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so'
```

Check that the directory is in your `sys.path`:

```
>>> import sys; print(filter(lambda p: 'lib-dynload' in p, sys.path))
['/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload']
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that fix your problem?

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, May 31 2009, 16:56:01)
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sqlite
>>> import sqlite3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2.5.5. Mac port of Python 2.5 now has this hint:

```
"py25-sqlite3 @2.5.4 (python, databases)
    This is a stub. sqlite3 is now built with python25"
```

And so an upgrade of the python25 port to `python25 @2.5.5_0` made the import work again.
Since sqlite3 is among the dependencies of python25,
it is built anew when upgrading python25.
Thus,

```
$ sudo port upgrade python25
```

does the trick on Mac OS X, ports collection.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem.
Steps to solve.

1. Download latest sqlite3 from sqlite website.   sqlite-autoconf*
2. Install that in 3 simple steps

   1. ./configure
   2. make
   3. make install
3. Rebuild the python
   make 
   make install