# Can't import Numpy in Python

Tags: python, import, numpy

I'm trying to write some code that uses Numpy.  However, I can't import it:

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262, May 15 2009, 10:22:27) 
[GCC 3.4.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I tried the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233320/cannot-import-sqlite-with-python-2-6):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.6.2/lib/python26.zip', '/usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.6.2/lib/python2.6', '/usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.6.2/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.6.2/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.6.2/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.6.2/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.6.2/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

and I searched for files named `numpy` in that path:

```
$ find /usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.6.2/bin/python -iname numpy\*
```

But nothing came up.

So...

- Are there any other places in which Python modules are commonly installed?
- How can I install numpy locally in my account, if it turns out that it isn't installed in the central areas?

Comment: Suse 9 64-bit on a corporate machine

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you installed it?

On debian/ubuntu:

```
aptitude install python-numpy
```

On windows:

[`http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/)

On other systems:

[`http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/)

```
$ tar xfz numpy-n.m.tar.gz
$ cd numpy-n.m
$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: Good question.  I had assumed that it's part of standard distributions.

Comment: How can I install it in a private area?  I don't have root permissions on the machine

Comment: use the --prefix install option. `python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/intel` - see distutils docs for more details at http://docs.python.org/install/

Comment: Modern instructions for installing on Windows: https://gehrcke.de/2015/02/how-to-set-up-a-64-bit-version-of-numpy-on-windows/

Answer (score 4):

Your sys.path is kind of unusual, as each entry is prefixed with /usr/intel. I guess numpy is installed in the usual non-prefixed place, e.g. it. /usr/share/pyshared/numpy on my Ubuntu system.

Try  `find / -iname '*numpy*'`

Answer (score 4):

The following command worked for me:

```
python.exe -m pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 2):

**To install it on Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

Comment: this is the answer as the error occurs when numpy not installed in system. You have to install it using above command then you will be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to import numpy in python 3.2.1 on windows 7.

Followed suggestions in above answer for numpy-1.6.1.zip as below after unzipping it

```
cd numpy-1.6
python setup.py install
```

but got an error with a statement as below

```
unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

For this error I found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) which suggested installing mingW. MingW was taking some time to install.

In the meanwhile tried to install numpy 1.6 again using the direct windows installer available at this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.1/)
the file name is "numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python3.2.exe"

Installation went smoothly and now I am able to import numpy without using mingW.

Long story short try using windows installer for numpy, if one is available.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling pyright worked perfectly for me on VS.

Comment: Although your answer might be right you should give a little more information why this is the case because its not realy obvious why this proposed solution would work. OP's question is from 9 years ago and your answer may apply now to which version (include this type of info as well: read - dark ages vs. landing on the moon differences)?!