# Python on Aptana Studio with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, configuration, aptana

I need help setting up aptana studio with python numpy.

I already have python configured with the studio. I downloaded the numpy package from http://www.numpy.org/ .

How do I configure my IDE with this API?

Comment: you need to rebuild your interpreter settings ... go remove your python interpreter. then re-add it and it should autodiscover any new libraries .... you have to do this pretty much any time you add libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unless I am missing something myself, API would be the wrong term, 'Application programming interface' does not refer to libraries.

Once you have numpy properly installed, just telling ipython or your code to 'import numpy' should make it usable in that code. There are also ways of just importing certain parts, I believe, but that is the quick, standard, and easy way to do it.

Additional help:

[Can't import Numpy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273203/cant-import-numpy-in-python)

http://www.scipy.org/Getting_Started#head-7343a18c246cbb5151cb9950b341731acc9060fa