# How to import numpy to python IDLE 2.7 on windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, anaconda

I have tried the following code on the python IDLE:

> import pip
>   pip.main(["install","numpy"])

and the output I got is :

Collecting numpy
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
[31m  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )[0m
[31mNo matching distribution found for numpy[0m

I also have tried to use the "pip install numpy" but still not leading to any result.

Comment: What does this have to do with Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following post the user is having the same issues as you do:

[Can't import Numpy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273203/cant-import-numpy-in-python)

And take a look over here:

[pip issue installing almost any library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370583/pip-issue-installing-almost-any-library)

Answer (score 0):

Try Downloading it [Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) it's suggested in [Scientific Python Install Page](https://scipy.org/install.html)