# python sqlite fails

Tags: python, sqlite

My program uses sqlite3 plus python. It works fine with python 2.6.2
I moved it another machine and installed 2.6.4 and running the program gave me this error

> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "/opt/python-2.6.4/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/**init**.py", line 24, in
>
> from dbapi2 import *
>
> File "/opt/python-2.6.4/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in
>
> from _sqlite3 import *
>
> ImportError: No module named _sqlite3

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233320/cannot-import-sqlite-with-python-2-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [cannot-import-sqlite-with-python-2-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233320/cannot-import-sqlite-with-python-2-6/).

You are missing the .so (shared object) - probably an installation step.

Comment: thanks .. installing the sqlite3-devel package and then compiled and installed ..now its working.